# Microsoft-R much slower than SQL

Tags: c#, sql, r, microsoft-r

I am using `sp_execute_external_script` to run an R script inside Microsoft R. **I call it from C#**. But I found the problem that although it's nothing complicated and it only works with 6000 rows more or less it takes like 7 seconds to complete. Therefore I have translated the script in pure **SQL** and it takes just 2-3 seconds (**also from C#**). So, I checked the performance as seen below, and the whole SP lasts 1.877 seconds average, the the R script 1.56 (`system.time`). So my question is why such a difference? Honestly, I can't  figure out why SQL is that much faster when there shouldn't be so much difference.

```
declare @start datetime = getdate()

EXEC sp_execute_external_script 
    @input_data_1   = N'select * from table' -- only 6000 rows approx.
    @name           = N't', 
    @params         = N'',
    @rscript        = N'
        # my R script
        OutputDataSet <- data.frame(field1, field2)
    '
declare @executionTimeInMilliseconds int = datediff(ms, @start, getdate())

print @executionTimeInMilliseconds
```

Comment: Does it run faster the second time if you call external script again shortly after the first one completes? There seems to be an R startup time in our implementation when it hasn't been used in a while

Comment: Yes, I do have also that start up time. Nevertheless, the time is much more than acceptable when running in Management Studio. The problem is when called from a C# controller.

Comment: Oh I see. When I read 'translated to pure sql', I thought you meant bypassing R/sp_execute_external_script entirely and performing the task in SQL instead

Comment: Yes, you read it right. I explain again: I have stored procedure that works as a wrapper (let's call it SP_R) and calls sp_execute_external_script. This is the script that goes pretty fast in management studio but slow when C# invokes it.

On the other hand, I also translated this wrapper SP. to SQL (let's call this one SP_SQL). The whole calculation runs also in the sql version which is the one that is much faster that R.

Answer (score 1):

Calling SQL from SQL itself is usually a lot faster since it doesn't need any context switch, no additional parsing and calling other processes.

A SQL execution engine is optimized so far that every step outside its own is slower. I can imagine this is the case here too. The overhead of a small function is of course much higher that from a long-running function, which probably skews your metrics here.